# Bounds of ellipse arc

Tags: automatic-ref-counting, bounds, ellipse

I need to find exact bounds of 2D transformed ellipse arc.

The entry data are:

1. **a** - ellipse radius x
2. **b** - ellipse radius y
3. **transform** - 2D transform with 0 translation (a, b, c, d, tx, ty)
4. startAngle - arc start angle
5. endAngle - arc end angle

I've used this topic answer to find the bounds of transformed ellipse
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91132/how-to-get-the-limits-of-rotated-ellipse

It works fine.

**What I have for now**

```
const rx2 = radiusX * radiusX;
const ry2 = radiusY * radiusY;

let maxX = Math.sqrt(rx2 * transform.a * transform.a + ry2 * transform.c * transform.c);
let maxY = Math.sqrt(rx2 * transform.b * transform.b + ry2 * transform.d * transform.d);
let minX = -maxX;
let minY = -maxY;
```

The next step is to find points p1, p2, p3, p4 (see picture)
So then I can check which points are within the startAngle and the endAngle.

[required points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOXP1.jpg)

The equation of ellipse is: 
[simple equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpSYJ.jpg)

The equation of transformed ellipse should be: 
[transformed equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWfD6.jpg)

In order to find required points the last equation has to be solved for x and y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got this.

So all I need is to apply inverted transform to points (minX, minY); (maxX, minY); (maxX, maxY); (maxX, minY);
And then use simple ellipse (mentioned above) and line equations to find four intersection points, which then should be transformed to global coordinates multiplying to transform.

Here is the code for one point

```
arcLineIntersection(lineStart, lineEnd, rx2, ry2, out) {
    const lineK = (lineEnd.y - lineStart.y) / (lineEnd.x - lineStart.x);

    if (Number.isFinite(lineK)) {
      const lineB = lineStart.y - lineK * lineStart.x;

      const a = lineK * lineK + ry2 / rx2;
      const b = 2 * lineK * lineB;

      const x = -b / (2 * a);
      const y = lineK * x + lineB;

      out.set(x, y);
    } else {
      const x = lineStart.x;
      const y = Math.sqrt(ry2 * (1 - x * x / rx2));

      out.set(x, y);
    }
  }
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptMy0.jpg)